# In one of the Table index size is 1.6 TB, we are not able to Rebuild that index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, enterprise-edition

In Sql server 2017 Enterprise Edition, one of our Clustered Indexes is more than 1.6 TB. We are unable to rebuild this index, it is failing while rebuilding due to log file full. We have added additional disk space as well, but the rebuild process is still failing.

Can any one give suggestions to fix the issue

Comment: it depends, are you on SQL Server Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Try to perform index reorganize+update statistics instead of the rebuild as a quick solution. Then maybe you should think over partitioning that big table.

Comment: We are using enterprise edition and we tried that also, but it also failing

Comment: @DBA_Fresher first check how much free space you have, for an index rebuild a minimum 2*`index size` space is required (the data file needs 1.6TB free space and 1.6 TB for log file) This changes in the case of `TEMPDB SORT` is on that means (tempdb free space needed is 1.6Tb and 1.6TB for log space)

Comment: Why don't we look at this a step higher. What level of fragmentation is the index at right now? Are you noticing performance impact at the current fragmentation level. Why is your CLUSTERED index fragmented to the point it needs a rebuild? What is the data type of your Key column?

Comment: Or to more generally ask Brendan's question, why do you think you need to rebuild this index? (Agreed with Denis on getting partitioning setup too.)

Comment: Just a note that on 2017 EE you have resumable index rebuild and on 2019 also resumable create. You can pause a rebuild, empty the log and then start it up again. (Pretty impressive.) I do agree with the others I must add, regarding whether rebuild is necessary in the fist place and partitioning might help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @J.D.: *"[...] why do you think you need to rebuild this index?"*.

Most of the time we see `avg_fragmentation_in_percent value` >30% and we get mad at it thinking: "Oh, that's why my SQL Server is not going fast! But with a new reorganized index it will be light bolt fast".

This is not the case, especially if you are using SSD, you don't have the read-and-write head of your Hard Drive going left and right picking up data.

Because you are on SQL Server Enterprise Edition I will give you 2 good ideas and 1 crazy idea:

1. Use `ALTER INDEX REBUILD WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW, ONLINE = ON);`
2. As suggested by @TiborKaraszi in the comment use [resumable index rebuild](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4987/sql-server-2017-resumable-online-index-rebuilds/)
3. Because you have already played around with the log file I found this [hacky idea](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/348546-crazy-idea-putting-sql-logs-into-ramdisk-thoughts) on the web. I will test it myself on my spare time.

Comment: The RamDisk trick for TempDB seems interesting. Just don't do it for TLogs because there is a serious risk of corrupting the service in case of server crash. Btw, this solution is interesting only in case of using the TempDB_Sort option.